# use virtualenv site-packages with other python installation

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a web application written in python that has to run on a shared linux from a really dumb provider (I even have to use CGI...).

When I had deployed the page, most things I have needed weren't available, so I had installed all of them locally in my home. No my provider decided to only support 64 Bit, hence all my local 32 Bit binaries are broken.

Now I have to fix the situation. I tried to use the (now available) global installations of python, sqlite3 and so forth by changing the she-bang in my main script and add a sys.path.append to the site-packages of my prior virtualenv installation.

The script is now executable and some libraries from site-packages are loaded, but not all and I don't know what the problem is and how to fix it. I was always satisfied by using virtualenv without understanding its internals.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What's going wrong? What errors are you getting? What packages are problematic? Why can't you set up a new virtualenv for 64Bit?

Comment: I get an import error for flask.ext.uploads. Other packages from virtualenv (including other flask.ext stuff) works. The problem is, that virtualenv is not available globally. I had to compile all that stuff locally from source. I can remember that it was not that easy to get everything to compile and run, therefore I wand to try not to start building the infrastructure from scratch.

Comment: Try installing `virtualenv` via `pip`. `pip` itself can be bootstrapped via the `get-pip` script if it is not available.